# Connect to Web service Using jquery( $.ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried to connect to to this web service:

> http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx

but it alert "error" to

This is the script that I used:

```
     var varType;
     var varUrl;
     var varData;
     var varContentType;
     var varDataType;
     var varProcessData;
     function SetValue() {
         varType = "POST";
         varUrl = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/FahrenheitToCelsius";
         varData = '{"Fahrenheit":"230"}';
         varContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
         varDataType = "json";
         varProcessData = true;
         CallService();
     }
     function CallService() {
         $.ajax({
             type: varType, 
             url: varUrl, 
             data: varData, 
             contentType: varContentType, 
             dataType: varDataType, 
             processdata: varProcessData, 
             success: function (msg) {
                 ServiceSucceeded(msg);
             },
             error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                 alert(xhr.statusText);
                alert(thrownError);
            } 
         });
     }

     function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
         alert("ServiceSucceeded");

         varType = null; varUrl = null; varData = null; varContentType = null; varDataType = null; varProcessData = null;
     }
```

What should I do?

Comment: You should read about the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: By the way, you don't need to set everything to `null`... the garbage collector takes care of that.

Comment: did you look what exactly are you getting back with firebug/webinspector? did you try to manualy do this from the console with preset variables?

Comment: The url, you want to request doesn't relay exists. w3school detects that you'r making an external request and throw an error. http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/FahrenheitToCelsius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`dataType: 'jsonp'`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) when doing cross-domain requests because of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: tnkx i will try your solution

Comment: This will not work. You can't just slap `dataType: 'jsonp'` on an AJAX request.

Comment: Well obviously the server also has to support this but jsonp is the only way to get JSON data from a cross-domain AJAX request.

Micha points out the real issue above, this is not a URL that is meant to be accessed from other sites.